# Basic , Sending data to database, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to PHP and so far I've managed to connect to my database, but when I try to send data to the database I don't get any script errors, but the data doesn't go through and I receive the message "Succesfully Created User!", which basically means the data has been sent right?

**Here is my script:**

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$con = mysql_connect("fdb13.awardspace.net", "myusername", "mypassword") or die(mysql_error());
if(!$con)
    die('Could not connectzzz: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("myusername" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" . mysql_error());

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM unitytut WHERE `user`='".$user."'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($numrows == 0)
{
    $pass = md5($pass);

    //$ins = "INSERT INTO unitytut (user, name, pass) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'John');";

        //$ins =  ("INSERT INTO `unitytut` (`user`), (`name`), (`pass`) VALUES ('' , 'John', 'Doe', 'John''John', 'Doe', 'John') ; ");

            $ins =  ("INSERT INTO `unitytut` (`user`), (`name`), (`pass`) VALUES ('' , '".$user."' , '".$name."', '".$pass."') ; ");


   if($ins)
        die("Succesfully Created User!");

    else
        die("ERROR");

}
else
{
    die("user already exists!");
}

?>
```

**I've tried several insert methods, but the only 3 functions that didn't receive the "ERROR" message was:**

```
$ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO unitytut (`user`), (`name`), (`pass`) VALUES ('' , '$user' , '$name', '$pass')" ) ;
```

**and**

```
$ins =  ("INSERT INTO `unitytut` (`user`), (`name`), (`pass`) VALUES ('' , 'John', 'Doe', 'John''John', 'Doe', 'John') ; ");
```

**and**

```
$ins =  ("INSERT INTO `unitytut` (`user`), (`name`), (`pass`) VALUES ('' , '".$user."' , '".$name."', '".$pass."') ; ");
```

I also have an ID in my table, but as I've been researching this issue without managing to fix it, I also read that I don't need to specify the ID in the script as the user is getting an ID automatically, but as I haven't gotten this to work I wouldn't know for sure.

I'm very new to php and databases in general, but I've been stuck on this for a while now, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Also any feedback on the way I posted this is also welcome, did I give you too much information, too many questions in one post, too much text etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: `mysql_query` doesn't work if you never did `mysql_connect`

Comment: I've already connected through mysql_connect, I only provided the code that I thought was neccecary. Sorry about that I'll send the whole code, and thanks for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should format your INSERT statement like this:

```
$ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO unitytut (`user`,`name`,`pass`) VALUES ('$user' , '$name', '$pass')" ) ;
```

However, `mysql_query` is deprecated, [**See this link**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and follow it's advice on using a newer extension

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked :) Now I can finally work on sending these signals from Unity. Unforitionally my reputation here isn't high enough yet to upvote you, but once it is I'll be sure to come back and do so. Cheers

Comment: @Anders no worries I'm glad it helped - you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick on the left if you see fit :-)

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ General rule of thumb here is not to ask the OP to accept your answer as the correct one, you need to let them coose as they see fit.

Comment: @Darren - the OP had clearly tried to upvote my answer as correct, and considering the OP is a new member they possibly do not know about the accepted answer tick.

Comment: As @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ mentioned you should really consider switching to either PDO or MYSQLi. If you use mysql_query when it gets deprecated you'll be left without anything to work with